# Is 50 minutes enough for a transfer at Incheon airport?

Tags: layovers, seoul

I will be flying Economy, so potentially at the back of a full plane! If the flight is delayed, I believe they will have to put me on the next one with available seats, but if it is on time, will they hold the connecting flight or hasten me through? I called the London office, but I couldn't really get an answer beyond stating that the minimum transfer time is 45 minutes. Could they deliberately schedule a flight to be just over that time to show that it is not the airline's fault if I do not make the gate? I can walk briskly, but I cannot run.

Comment: Not familiar with the layout of Incheon, but in most airports an international-to-international connection within the same terminal in 50 minutes definitely isn’t a problem. If you have difficult moving around don’t hesitate to request assistance, they can probably dispatch someone go transport you from one gate to the other (depending on airports this may be either a wheelchair or some kind of electric vehicle, think golf cart without the roof). They are quite likely to hold the connecting flight for a few minutes if required.

Comment: Great, thanks for that!

Comment: Single ticket, or two tickets?

Comment: I haven't tried transfer in Incheon so I don't write it as an answer. Korean airports are really convenient and well-organized, so I wouldn't worry too much.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, if an airline is willing to sell you a ticket with a short connection, they're confident that you can make it: otherwise they have to reschedule you on a later flight, and that messes up their seat availability, and they might even have to pay you compensation for the delay.

Of course, this assumes that you do have a single ticket. A short connection is never a good idea if you have separate tickets.

Anecdotically, I have had a 50-minute connection at Incheon, and it wasn't a problem. This was an international-to-international connection, staying in terminal 1. [There an airside transfer between the terminals](https://www.airport.kr/ap_lp/en/trn/intro/t1trnt1t2/t1trnt1t2.do), but I expect it adds some time. If you have to pass immigration, 50 minutes is too short pretty much anywhere.